# unable to install ruby 2.3.8 in macos m1

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Unable to install ruby 2.3.8 in MacOS M1 chip below is the error I'm getting. Tried multiple ways

```
trial 1: rvm install 2.3.4 -C --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.0/bin/openssl

Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
```

Still nothing works. Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Install openssl 1.0 with this brew tap ([source](https://github.com/rbenv/homebrew-tap/pull/2#issuecomment-1047430606))

```
brew install nutcracker/tap/openssl@1.0
```

then just install ruby using:

```
rvm install 2.3.8 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download an old version of openssl and bind it to the ruby installation.

Download: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/OpenSSL_1_0_2u

```
$> tar -xzf openssl-OpenSSL_1_0_2u.tar.gz
$> cd openssl-1.0.2u
$> ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
$> make
$> make test
$> sudo make install
```

And then install ruby using:

```
$> arch -x86_64 rvm install 2.3.8 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
```

Source: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5033

Comment: Updating certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.

Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/praneeth/.rvm/log/1654768836_ruby-2.3.8/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: @RebelRider Can you try adding this `arch -x86_64 ` as prefix to make command ?

Comment: You mean "arch -x86_64 make" like this

Comment: Any other alternate solution